# RPi3 can't find ffe0 service via Bluepy python

Tags: python-2.7, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3

I have an RPi2 with GPIO-hm10 ble module that connects and communicates with a ble-relay board (RB1).  I want to replace the RPi2 with an RPi3.  So I tested the RPi3 with an identical test-unit relay board RB2 and using this python script the RPi3 can connect and communicate with the RB2.  So I was ready to swap them.

Here is the visual of it:

[image: RPi2 RPi3 RB1 RB2]

I also tried connecting to both relay boards (RB1 & RB2) from the BLE scanner app on the iphone and I can connect and send commands just fine by writing to their characterstic.

I can connect and pair and trust both boards from the RPi3 via bluetoothctl and see their UUID services just fine.  But when I run my python code to toggle the relays on RB2:

```
import bluepy.btle as btle
p = btle.Peripheral("00:0E:0B:00:75:12", "random")
s = p.getServiceByUUID("0000ffe0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")
c = s.getCharacteristics()[0]
c.write("o", "utf-8")
p.disconnect()
```

I get this error on RB1 only::

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bluepy/btle.py", line 449, in getServiceByUUID
raise BTLEException(BTLEException.GATT_ERROR, "Service %s not found" % (uuid.getCommonName()))
bluepy.btle.BTLEException: Service ffe0 not found
```

But the service is uuid is correct, here is a terminal session output.  As you can see, I can connect to the RB1 and see the UUID Services including the ffe0 I need:

```
[bluetooth]# connect 00:0E:0B:00:75:12
Attempting to connect to 00:0E:0B:00:75:12
[CHG] Device 00:0E:0B:00:75:12 Connected: yes
Connection successful
[CHG] Device 00:0E:0B:00:75:12 UUIDs:
00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
     00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
     0000ffe0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[bluetooth]# info 00:0E:0B:00:75:12
Device 00:0E:0B:00:75:12
     Name: BT Bee-BLE
     Alias: BT Bee-BLE
     Paired: no
     Trusted: yes
     Blocked: no
     Connected: yes
     LegacyPairing: no
     UUID: Generic Access Profile
  (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
     UUID: Generic Attribute Profile
(00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
     UUID: Unknown
  (0000ffe0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
```

Why is that happening?  Could something be saved somewhere in the tsrb430 RB1 that could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of inspecting the btle.py file, I noticed the getServices() function was not being called.  I added a call to it and now it find can find the service:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import bluepy.btle as btle
p = btle.Peripheral("00:0E:0B:00:75:12", "random")
services=p.getServices()
for service in services:
   print service
s = p.getServiceByUUID("0000ffe0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")
c = s.getCharacteristics()[0]
c.write("e", "utf-8")
p.disconnect()
```